# Can NASA's sound recordings of planets, and photos of astronomical bodies, be used freely in for-profit projects?

Tags: nasa

**Can NASA's sound recordings, and photos of, astronomical bodies be used in for-profit/commercial projects (movies, video games)?**

I've read NASA's Media Usage Guidelines, but am still not sure.

(here's the link https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/guidelines/index.html)

Comment: I have a hunch that this legal information is available on a NASA site and probably links to that on the specific sites where you find the recordings. Can you show the link to the NASA's Media Usage Guidelines and explain what it is specifically about what you've read that you don't understand? You might consider moving your question to [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) where they will be better prepared to help you understand the details of that document.

Comment: *I've read NASA's Media Usage Guidelines,*  **Add the link** please.

Comment: Ask NASA !  Why ask anyone else (except a lawyer in that field) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question asking for legal advice.